# Why does filter returns the same array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to remove an item using filter, but it returns the same array...
Im new to react.. so pls keep that in mind with the answers :)

*** method ***

```
removeItemHandler = (id) => {
    if (this.state.selectedProducts.length <= 0){
      return
    }
      let carsSelected = this.state.selectedProducts.filter(item => {
        return item !== id})
        debugger;
        console.log(`item removed`, carsSelected);}
```

***debugger (clicked 3 items)***

```
  removeItemHandler = (id) => { ***id = {id: 2, name: "Bugatti", price: 3200000, description: "Extremely Fast", total: 0, …}
***
    if (this.state.selectedProducts.length <= 0){
      return
    }
      let carsSelected = this.state.selectedProducts.filter(item => ***{ carsSelected = (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]***

        return item !== id}) ***id = {id: 2, name: "Bugatti", price: 3200000, description: "Extremely Fast", total: 0, …}***
        debugger;
```

***console.log returns the same array***

Comment: Provide the `selectedProducts` json .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should filter by `item.id` instead of `item`

```
let carsSelected = this.state.selectedProducts.filter(item => item.id !== id.id)
//                                                                 ^^
```

Note that you are passing an object as `id` parameter. And you are comparing two objects. This is not easily done in JavaScript. Object equality is not how it seems. For example:

```
var firstObject = {
    id: 1,
    foo: "foo",
    bar: "bar"
};

var secondObject = {
    id: 1,
    foo: "foo",
    bar: "bar"
};


console.log(firstObject === secondObject); // with triple "="
// Output: false

console.log(firstObject == secondObject);  // with double "="
// Output: false
```

Even both objects have the same properties with same values, they are not same objects.

Instead of comparing whole objects, you can compare their **unique identifiers**

For further reading: [Object comparison in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript)

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare the id of the item with the id you have passed to filter out.

```
let carsSelected = this.state.selectedProducts.filter(item => { return item.id !== id.id});
```

Comment: Please note that the parameter `id` is not an identifier, it is an object. So `item.id !== id` always returns `true`.

Comment: Oh yes, I didn't notice that. You can't compare the values of two objects using equality operator. In this case two objects will always give true for **!==** if the reference of those objects are different.